# Show that $\text{cl}_S(H)=\text{cl}_TH\cap S$

Tags: general-topology

I have the following exercise in my textbook:

If $H$ is a subset of a topological space $T$, denote by $\text{cl}_TH$ the closure of $H$ in $T$, by $\text{int}_TH$ the interior of $H$ in $T$, and by $\partial_TH$ the boundary of $H$ in $T$.

Show that if $S$ is a subspace of $T$ (with the subspace topology) in $H\subset S$ then

$$\text{cl}_S(H)=\text{cl}_TH\cap S$$

Here's my approach:

$x\in \text{cl}_SH\Leftrightarrow x\in\{x\in S : U\cap S\neq \emptyset \forall \text{ open } U\in\mathcal{T}_S, x\in U\} \Leftrightarrow x\in\{x\in S : U\cap H\neq\emptyset \forall \text{ open }U\in\{U\cap S:U\in \mathcal{T}\},x\in U\} \Leftrightarrow x\in\{x\in T: U\cap S\cap H \neq \emptyset \forall \text{ open } U\in\mathcal{T},x\in U\} \Leftrightarrow x\in\{x\in T: U\cap H\neq \emptyset ,\forall \text{ open } U\in\mathcal{T},x\in U\} \cap S \Leftrightarrow \text{cl}_TH\cap S$

So we proved that $\text{cl}_SH\subset \text{cl}_TH\cap S$

We now prove the converse:

$x\in\text{cl}_TH\cap S\Leftrightarrow x\in\{x\in T : H\cap U \neq \emptyset \forall \text{ open } U\in \mathcal{T}, x\in U\}\cap x\in S\Leftrightarrow x\in\{x\in S : H\cap U\neq \emptyset \forall \text{ open } U \in \mathcal{T}_S, x\in U\} = \text{cl}_SH$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that such "chains of formulae" proofs are quite unreadable. I'm a proponent of more reasoning and fewer symbols, e.g.:

Suppose that $C$ is a $S$-closed set that contains $H$. Then we can write $C = C' \cap S$, where $C'$ is $T$-closed. As $H \subseteq C$ we have $H \subseteq C'$ as well and so $\text{cl}_T(H) \subseteq C'$ by minimality of the closure and so $\text{cl}_T(H) \cap S \subseteq C' \cap S = C$ as well. Taking in particular $C = \text{cl}_S(H)$ (which fits the bill: $S$-closed and contains $H$), we get $\text{cl}_T(H) \cap S \subseteq \text{cl}_S(H)$.

OTOH, $\text{cl}_T(H) \cap S$ is an $S$-closed subset that contains $H$ so by minimality again $\text{cl}_S(H) \subseteq \text{cl}_T(H) \cap S$ and equality ensues.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually my book gives a similar answer to yours. Is my way of proving it not correct though? I guess that the way you do it is better for understanding the subject deeper.

Comment: @user It's mostly unreadable and unstructured; clean it up, and give it a structure and it could become correct.